# Convert the Cauchy-Euler equation into a constant coefficients equation:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x^2y'' - xy' + 8y = x^2 + x$$

I need you to review my answer:

Let $Y = Ax^2 + Bx + C$

$$ \begin{align*}
x^2  Y'' - xY' + 8Y & = x^2 + x  \\
x^2  (2A) - x  (2Ax + B) + 8  (Ax^2 + Bx+ C) &= x^2 + x  \\
(2A - 2A - 8A)x^2 + (-B - 8B)x - (8C) &= x^2 + x \\
(-8A)x^2 + (-9B)x + (-8C) &= x^2 + x
\end{align*}$$

$\\$

$$\begin{align}
\therefore C &= 0 \\
 -9B &= 1 \implies B = -1/9 \\
-8A &= 1 \implies A = -1/8
\end{align}$$

$\\$

$$Y = -x^2/8 - x/9$$

Is that correct ???

Comment: Your question title seems to be a bit different than your question by the way. It appears you're asking us to verify if your particular solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check a solution to *any* differential equation is to substitute it back into the equation itself. If your solution is correct, the equality should hold. Where $Y = -\frac{x^2}{8} - \frac x9$, $Y' =  -\frac{x}{4} - \frac 19$, and $Y''=-\frac 14$, we have

$$x^2\left(-\frac 14\right) - x\left(-\frac{x}{4} - \frac 19\right) + 8\left(-\frac{x^2}{8} - \frac x9\right) = x^2 + x$$

$$-\frac {x^2}{4} + \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac x9 - x^2 - \frac {8x}9\ = x^2 + x$$

$$ - x^2 - \frac {7x}9\ = x^2 + x$$

It appears that your solution is incorrect. The equality in the last line does not hold. It's *similar* to the correct answer though. Go back and check this line... it looks like you have sign errors.

$$(2A - 2A - 8A)x^2 + (-B - 8B)x - (8C) = x^2 + x $$